# How to read a file twice

Tags: java

I am trying to read the file twice but it seems only the first while loop is running.Basically, I have used the first while loop to count elements and I assigned the size of the array. I have used the second one to call the method and pass the string(each element). I tried to perform both tasks by using one while loop but I am having a difficulty to set the size of the array.

Please help if anyone knows how to do it. I am looking to hear from you guys.

Thank you in advance

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader("first.txt"));
    int count = 0;
    while(scan.hasNext())
    {
        count ++;
        String s = scan.next(); 
    }

    ArrayList<String> []words = new ArrayList[count];
    while(scan.hasNext())
    {   
        String f = scan.next();
        hash(f,count);   //call method
    }
    scan.close();
    //System.out.println(count);


}
```

Comment: Have you tried resetting scan in between the calls? Because its `.hasNext()` method is at the end when you are doing the second iteration.

Comment: The first loop ended because `scan.hasNext()` returned false. You've done nothing to `scan` before the next loop, so what makes you think `hasNext()` will return anything other than false (like it did last time...)

Comment: I tried to use reset(); but nothing seems to work. Is there anyway to go back to the first line of the file?

Comment: Close the file, open with an entirely new FileReader and Scanner.  There are other ways, but that's guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify a size of an ArrayList.  It will handle resizing as necessary.

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader("first.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(scan.hasNext())
    {   
        String s = scan.next();
        words.add(s);
    }
    scan.close();
}
```